# I'm trying to script a SSH connection test using a list of test users against a list of hosts using bash, can you help?

Tags: shell-script, ssh

I'm trying to test the ssh connection of a set of hosts using a corresponding set of test user accounts.

ie: `testuser1 test ssh connection to server1`, `testuser2 test ssh connection to server2`, `testuser3 test ssh connection to server3` ect.

Each test user is logging in using a private key:
`ssh -i ~/keys/testuser1key testuser1@server1`

However, I'm running into an issue when putting this information into a variable. Here is what I have for a script so far:

```
for host in $(cat hosts)
do
   if
      ssh -i $host 'true' exit
   then
      echo "SSH connection for $host ok"
   else
      echo "SSH connection for $host failed"
   fi
done
$SHELL
```

The `host` file looks like this:

```
~/keys/testuser1key testuser1@server1
~/keys/testuser2key testuser2@server2
~/keys/testuser3key testuser3@server3
...
```

I am getting errors such as `could not resolve hostname true`

I think the space in the `host` file are what's breaking the script. I've used a similar script no issue when running my user account and no "-i" ssh flag. (`ssh myuseraccount@testserver1`)

Any help or suggestions on a better way to do this is appreciated!

Comment: Could you use Ansible instead of bash? Much easier with Ansible.

Comment: @AdamJRichardson this is good for learning `bash`

Answer (score 7):

I'd suggest using a `while read` loop so that you can assign whitespace-separated tokens to individual variables, rather than relying on the implicit split+glob behavior of `$(cat hosts)`

The only tricky bit is that `read` reads from standard input by default - and so does `ssh`. So you either need to pass the `-n` flag to tell ssh to read from /dev/null:

```
while read -r identityfile host; do
  if ssh -n -i "$identityfile" "$host" true
  then
    echo "SSH connection for $host ok"
  else
    echo "SSH connection for $host failed"
  fi
done < hosts
```

or tell `read` to read from a different file descriptor:

```
while read -u3 -r identityfile host; do
  if ssh -i "$identityfile" "$host" true
  then
    echo "SSH connection for $host ok"
  else
    echo "SSH connection for $host failed"
  fi
done 3< hosts
```

---

Note: you've made things somewhat difficult by using `~` rather than `$HOME` for example to prefix the identity file portion of your hosts file. Quoting `"$identityfile"` prevents tilde expansion by the shell; however leaving it *un*quoted (as `$identityfile`) is dangerous because it permits word splitting and filename generation<sup>1</sup>. It *seems* that at least the OpenSSH implementation of `ssh` expands `~` itself, but if your ssh implementation doesn't, then extra processing would be required to handle it properly.

<sup>1</sup> in this context it is filename generation (globbing) that is the primary concern, since if the name contains whitespace the whole approach is flawed.

Comment: `man ssh_config`, "_for user configurations, shell-like ‘~’ references to user home directories_"

Comment: @roaima I was thinking of using `"${identityfile/#~/$HOME}"`, but tbh I think I'd do something KISS like replacing `< hosts` with `< <(sed 's/^~/$HOME/' hosts)`

Comment: Even better (and I've learned today that you can anchor to start-of-string with # in a substitution too)